# Binaries of gcc 4.7 for windows

Tags: windows, gcc

where can I download from binaries for gcc 4.7 for windows platform?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend TDM builds of GCC, however not 4.7 yet - but maybe you may ask author for something new?

It is available: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download

Answer (score 2):

[Try it compilers assembly](http://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/downloads/list).

Answer (score 1):

The latest I can find is MinGW-w64 [GCC 4.6.3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/).

Answer (score 0):

Some windows binaries I saw here http://www.comsytec.com/products/gnu-binaries/gcc-binaries.html but perhaps lower versions will be also suitable depends on your requirements

Comment: no problem I've already downloaded them from stephan's lavavej website.